# For Loop and Appending to Vector in R

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

I am trying to create a For Loop in R to fill a Vector with Forecasted values, generated via the auto.arima function.

I am new to R, so I am not sure if this is done correctly.

The code I am using is the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forecast)
dfts <- ts(df$Price_REG1) 
fc=c()
for (i in 0:7) {
  modArima <- auto.arima(dfts[0+(i*24):168+(i*24)])
  forecast <- forecast(modArima, h=24)
  forecast_values <- forecast$mean
  fc <- append(fc, forecast_values)
}
```

I use longer sets in reality, but made it smaller here to make it more understandable.

What I am trying to achieve is to use the first week of data (168 hours in one week) to estimate the coefficients for the model. Then I want to put the generated predictions for the first 24 hours after the training set in the Vector `fc`.
I then want to move the window one day, reestimate the coefficients and generate the forecasts for the following day and saving them into the Vector.

I am a bit unsure on the `dfts[0+(i*24):168+(i*24)]` part, since `df <- df[0:168]`, doesn't work, but needs the `df <- df[0:168,]`. But if I put `dfts[0+(i*24):168+(i*24)]` I get

> Error in [.default(dfts, 0 + (i * 24):874 + (i * 24), ) :    incorrect
> number of dimensions

EDIT :
Sample of Data:

```
structure(c(28.78, 28.45, 27.9, 27.52, 27.54, 26.55, 25.83, 25.07, 
25.65, 26.15, 26.77, 27.4, 28.08, 28.69, 29.37, 29.97, 30.46, 
30.39, 30.06, 29.38, 27.65, 27.33, 25.88, 24.81, 12.07, 13.13, 
19.07, 21.12, 24.29, 26.27, 27.74, 28.39, 29.37, 29.95, 29.91, 
29.96, 29.94, 29.94, 30.18, 30.96, 31.2, 30.98, 30.35, 29.27, 
28.17, 28.02, 27.69, 24.39, 18.93, 9.98, 1.53, 0.14, 0.85, 9.92, 
24.48, 26.68, 28.12, 28.58, 28.16, 28.78, 28.31, 28.44, 28.96, 
29.86, 30.15, 30.07, 29.54, 29.11, 27.91, 27.03, 25.7, 22.04, 
21.73, 15.95, 16.23, 6.45, 3.83, 4.03, 4.04, 19.07, 17.49, 24.18, 
24.94, 25.11, 24.94, 24.95, 25.25, 26.33, 27.36, 28.88, 29.58, 
29.42, 27.71, 27.4, 27.37, 25.77, 26.65, 27.13, 27.11, 27.42), tsp = c(1, 
5.125, 24), class = "ts")
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `forecast` package so have little to add - but this looks like the kind of code someone who is used to C might write. So just a reminder - R is 1-indexed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example with built-in data set `AirPassengers` on how to run a rolling forecast with package `forecast`.

The code below makes use of time series functions

- `window` to subset objects of class `"ts"`;
- `frequency` and `start` to get those attributes.

The output vector is created beforehand, not extended in the loop with `append`.

```r
library(forecast)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#>   method            from
#>   as.zoo.data.frame zoo
data("AirPassengers", package = "datasets")

fc <- ts(
  data = rep(NA, length(AirPassengers)), 
  start = start(AirPassengers), 
  frequency = frequency(AirPassengers)
)

start <- start(AirPassengers)[1]
freq <- frequency(AirPassengers)
i_fc <- seq_len(freq)
fc[i_fc] <- AirPassengers[i_fc]

for(i in 1:11) {
  w <- window(AirPassengers, start = start + i - 1L, end = c(start + i - 1L, freq))
  modArima <- auto.arima(w)
  y <- forecast(modArima, h = freq)$mean
  i_fc <- i_fc + freq
  fc[i_fc] <- y
}

plot(cbind(AirPassengers, fc))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

I believe that the code below forecasts the next day given a certain initial number of days.

```r
library(forecast)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#>   method            from
#>   as.zoo.data.frame zoo

fill_first_periods <- function(x, weeks = 1L, week_days) {
  if(missing(week_days)) week_days <- 7L
  fc <- ts(
    data = rep(NA, length(x)), 
    start = start(x), 
    frequency = frequency(x)
  )
  i_fc <- seq_len(frequency(x) * week_days * weeks)
  fc[i_fc] <- x[i_fc]
  fc
}

# not enough data to run an example for 1 week
# three days only
weeks <- 1L
week_days <- 3L
fc <- fill_first_periods(dfts, weeks = weeks, week_days) 
n <- length(fc)

i_last <- length(fc[!is.na(fc)])
h <- frequency(fc)
curr_start <- start(fc)
curr_end <- c(curr_start[1] + weeks*week_days - 1L, frequency(fc))
for(i in 2:(end(fc)[1] - 1L)) {
  if(n - i_last < h) {
    h <- end(fc)[2]
    i_fc <- tail(seq_len(n), h)
  } else {
    i_fc <- (i_last + 1L):(i_last + h)
    i_last <- i_last + h
  }
  w <- window(dfts, start = curr_start, end = curr_end)
  modArima <- auto.arima(w)
  fc[i_fc] <- forecast(modArima, h = h)$mean
  #
  curr_start[1] <- curr_start[1L] + 1L
  curr_end <- c(curr_end[1L] + 1L, h)
}

plot(cbind(dfts, fc))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. So in this example, you are setting the frequency to `frequency = frequency(AirPassengers)` so I guess this automatically finds the seasonality? I see know that I have messed up with the indexing.. But other than that, as far as I can tell, my example and your example should create the same results?

Comment: @SimonRydstedt this automatically finds the seasonality, yes. As for your data, I can only guess that the code in my answer needs to be adapted to your problem. Can you post sample data? If you can, edit the question with the output of `dput(dfts)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(dfts, 100))`.

Comment: I have done that now. I realized that `start <- start(AirPassengers)[1]` did not work, so I changed the data to a vector instead by `vec1 <- df$Price `, but after this, if I run `frequency = frequency(vec1)` the frequency comes `1` instead of `24`.

Comment: And the real code I was trying is: `for (i in 0:333) {
  modArima <- auto.arima(dfts_4[0+(i*24):17544+(i*24)])` that is. a two year window that moves 333 times.

Comment: Based on this I guess I would have to edit your code to `w <- window(dfts, start = start + i - 1L, end = c(start + i - 1L, 17544))`

Comment: @SimonRydstedt See if the edit does what you want. Since there were not enough data for 7 days weeks, I created a variable `week_days` with a smaller value. You will have to change this.